# TPL Dataflow, can I query whether a data block is marked complete but has not yet completed?

Tags: c#, concurrency, task-parallel-library, message-passing, tpl-dataflow

Given the following:

```
BufferBlock<int> sourceBlock = new BufferBlock<int>();
TransformBlock<int, int> targetBlock = new TransformBlock<int, int>(element =>
{
    return element * 2;
});

sourceBlock.LinkTo(targetBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

//feed some elements into the buffer block
for(int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++)
{
    sourceBlock.SendAsync(i);
}

sourceBlock.Complete();

targetBlock.Completion.ContinueWith(_ =>
{
    //notify completion of the target block
});
```

The `targetBlock` never seems to complete and I think the reason is that all the items in the `TransformBlock` `targetBlock` are waiting in the output queue as I have not linked the `targetBlock` to any other Dataflow block. However, what I actually want to achieve is a notification when (A) the `targetBlock` is notified of completion AND (B) the input queue is empty. I do not want to care whether items still sit in the output queue of the `TransformBlock`. How can I go about that? Is the only way to get what I want to query the completion status of the `sourceBlock` AND to make sure the `InputCount` of the `targetBlock` is zero? I am not sure this is very stable (is the `sourceBlock` truly only marked completed if the last item in the `sourceBlock` has been passed to the `targetBlock`?). Is there a more elegant and more efficient way to get to the same goal?

Edit: I just noticed even the "dirty" way to check on completion of the `sourceBlock` AND `InputCount` of the `targetBlock` being zero is not trivial to implement. Where would that block sit? It cannot be within the `targetBlock` because once above two conditions are met obviously no message is processed within `targetBlock` anymore. Also checking on the completion status of the `sourceBlock` introduces a lot of inefficiency.

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: Because I complete one process once all items in the targetBlock complete processing even when items remain in the outQueue. One reason is the completion of that process and another is the measurement of latency, throughput performance. The linked next data block may take a lot longer to process all remaining items in the outQueue

Comment: Why not just wait on the task for the source block?  You don't need to have a block attached to that, just a continuation on the `Completion` property of the source block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can't directly do this. It's possible you could get this information from some `private` fields using reflection, but I wouldn't recommend doing that.

But you can do this by creating custom blocks. In the case of `Complete()` it's simple: just create a block that forwards each method to the original block. Except `Complete()`, where it will also log it.

In the case of figuring out when processing of all items is complete, you could link your block to an intermediate `BufferBlock`. This way, the output queue will be emptied quickly and so checking `Completed` of the internal block would give you fairly accurate measurement of when the processing is complete. This would affect your measurements, but hopefully not significantly.

Another option would be to add some logging at the end of the block's delegate. This way, you could see when processing of the last item was finished.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if the `TransformBlock` had a `ProcessingCompleted` event that would fire when the block has completed the processing of all messages in its queue, but there is no such event. Below is an attempt to rectify this omission. The `CreateTransformBlockEx` method accepts an `Action<Exception>` handler, that is invoked when this "event" occurs.

The intention was to always invoke the handler before the final completion of the block. Unfortunately in the case that the supplied [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.cancellationtoken) is canceled, the completion (cancellation) happens first, and the handler is invoked some milliseconds later. To fix this inconsistency would require some tricky workarounds, and may had other unwanted side-effects, so I am leaving it as is.

```
public static IPropagatorBlock<TInput, TOutput>
    CreateTransformBlockEx<TInput, TOutput>(Func<TInput, Task<TOutput>> transform,
    Action<Exception> onProcessingCompleted,
    ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions dataflowBlockOptions = null)
{
    if (onProcessingCompleted == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(onProcessingCompleted));
    dataflowBlockOptions = dataflowBlockOptions ?? new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions();

    var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<TInput, TOutput>(transform,
        dataflowBlockOptions);
    var bufferBlock = new BufferBlock<TOutput>(dataflowBlockOptions);

    transformBlock.LinkTo(bufferBlock);
    PropagateCompletion(transformBlock, bufferBlock, onProcessingCompleted);
    return DataflowBlock.Encapsulate(transformBlock, bufferBlock);

    async void PropagateCompletion(IDataflowBlock block1, IDataflowBlock block2,
        Action<Exception> completionHandler)
    {
        try
        {
            await block1.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch { }
        var exception = 
            block1.Completion.IsFaulted ? block1.Completion.Exception : null;
        try
        {
            // Invoke the handler before completing the second block
            completionHandler(exception);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (exception != null) block2.Fault(exception); else block2.Complete();
        }
    }
}

// Overload with synchronous lambda
public static IPropagatorBlock<TInput, TOutput>
    CreateTransformBlockEx<TInput, TOutput>(Func<TInput, TOutput> transform,
    Action<Exception> onProcessingCompleted,
    ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions dataflowBlockOptions = null)
{
    return CreateTransformBlockEx<TInput, TOutput>(
        x => Task.FromResult(transform(x)), onProcessingCompleted,
        dataflowBlockOptions);
}
```

The code of the local function `PropagateCompletion` mimics the [source code](https://source.dot.net/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/Internal/Common.cs.html#43ef227d2325fbe9) of the [`LinkTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformblock-2.linkto) built-in method, when invoked with the [`PropagateCompletion = true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowlinkoptions.propagatecompletion) option.

Usage example:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var downloader = CreateTransformBlockEx<string, string>(async url =>
{
    return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
}, onProcessingCompleted: ex =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Download completed {(ex == null ? "OK" : "Error")}");
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing it is not right to use a IPropagator Block as a leaf terminal. But still your requirement can be fulfilled by asynchronously checking the output buffer of the TargetBlock for output messages and then consuming then so that the buffer could be emptied.

```
    `  BufferBlock<int> sourceBlock = new BufferBlock<int>();
       TransformBlock<int, int> targetBlock = new TransformBlock<int, int> 
       (element =>
       {

        return element * 2;
        });
        sourceBlock.LinkTo(targetBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { 
        PropagateCompletion = true });

        //feed some elements into the buffer block
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
             sourceBlock.SendAsync(i);
        }

        sourceBlock.Complete();

        bool isOutputAvailable = await targetBlock.OutputAvailableAsync();
        while(isOutputAvailable)
        {
            int value = await targetBlock.ReceiveAsync();

            isOutputAvailable = await targetBlock.OutputAvailableAsync();
        }


        await targetBlock.Completion.ContinueWith(_ =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Target Block Completed");//notify completion of the target block
        });
```

`

Comment: If you want to empty the buffer of a `TransformBlock`, you can just link it to a [`NullTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.nulltarget) like this: `targetBlock.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<int>());`